# How to remove any illegal new lines appears within a text files using vim text editor?

Tags: mysql, vim, replace

I am trying to repair a data file so I can use MySQL DATA LOAD INFILE TO IMPORT DATA INTO database.

The problem that I am having with the file is that there are lengthy text but it contains a new line with in the text. Also a new line means a new record. This is making it hard for me to import the records into MySQL.

How can I use vim in linux to search for illegal new lines and replace them with a space?

Illegal new line: if a new line is found between a comma ( , ) and ( ,012d000 )

This is a sample data of the file

```
VST-65654,a0Jd000000FM8cBEAT,Blah,2013-10-22 10:46:30.000000,Blah Blah,2014-01-20 20:27:42.000000,2013-10-18 14:00:00.000000,005d0000002biR4AAI,001d000001NEh0oAAD,In Person,Unscheduled,Grow Applications,High,this is the body

of this 
log test
where I need to

remove all extra new lines,012d0000000ppiXAAQ
VST-122549,a0Jd000000GVwtyEAD,Blah,2013-10-31 18:17:50.000000,Blah,2013-11-06 18:07:47.000000,2013-10-31 18:10:00.000000,005d0000002biR9AAI,001d000001NEaQgAAL,In Person,Scheduled,Grow Applications,Medium,One more long paragraph

where I need to remove all extra

new lines

,012d0000000ppiABCD
```

The fields are separated by a comma ( , ) and the new record should begin when a new line \n is found.  How can I do such a search replace to fix this issue?

Or how can I replace all unescaped commas with a double quotes? That is, if I find \, don't touch it, but if you find a comma with replace it with ","

Thanks

Comment: You're not going to be able to reliably do this programmatically, you need to get your input data formatted properly. String data should be enclosed in quotes, and have internal quotes escaped. Once this is accomplished you need not worry about line breaks and/or commas inside string data.

Comment: yeah, that problem is that I don't have a way to export the data again. So I need to work with it as much as I can

Answer (score 2):

```
g/^VST/,-/,012d000/j!
```

Use the global command, `:g` to join together, `:j`, the line starting with `VST` with all the lines through the next instance of `012d000`.

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :j
:h [range]
```

Comment: What does the - mean/do in this situation? (g/^VST/,/,012d000/j! also works)

Comment: The search pattern in the range, `/,012d000/` means find the next line matching this pattern. We use `-` or `.-1` to start 1 line above the current line so in the case where `VST` and `,012d000` are on the same line the `:join` is a no-op instead of matching to the next record's `,012d000`. `g/^VST/,/,012d000/j!` will mangle records that fit on a single line with the next record.

Answer (score 1):

My regex foo isn't powerfull enough to do that in a single command but you could create a macro to achieve what you want. The following worked for the input you gave

Go to start of file

```
gg
```

Start recording

```
qq
```

Find next `,012d`

```
/,012d<CR>
```

Go up one line

```
k
```

Enter visual mode

```
v
```

Go to previous comma

```
?,<CR>
```

Replace all new line chars

```
:s/\n//g<CR>
```

Go down one line

```
j
```

Finish recording

```
q
```

Repeat

```
@q
```

Result

```
VST-65654,a0Jd000000FM8cBEAT,Blah,2013-10-22 10:46:30.000000,Blah Blah,2014-01-20 20:27:42.000000,2013-10-18 14:00:00.000000,005d0000002biR4AAI,001d000001NEh0oAAD,In Person,Unscheduled,Grow Applications,High,this is the body of this log test where I need to remove all extra new lines,012d0000000ppiXAAQ
VST-122549,a0Jd000000GVwtyEAD,Blah,2013-10-31 18:17:50.000000,Blah,2013-11-06 18:07:47.000000,2013-10-31 18:10:00.000000,005d0000002biR9AAI,001d000001NEaQgAAL,In Person,Scheduled,Grow Applications,Medium,One more long paragraph where I need to remove all extra new lines ,012d0000000ppiABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Peter Rincker's answer.  As for the question you asked at the end, you can replace all the un-escaped commas with `","` using

```
:%s/\\\@<!,/","/g
```

Here, `\\` represents a literal backslash and `\@<!` is a modifier.  (See `:help /\@<!`.)

The problem with this solution is that you have not correctly defined what an un-escaped comma is.  For example, `\\,` is an escaped backslash followed by an un-escaped comma.  I believe that `/\\\@<!\%(\\\\\)*\zs,/` is the correct pattern, but I do not say it is pretty.  It is a little better if you use the "very magic" version:  `/\v\\@<!%(\\\\)*\zs,/`.